# “GYIAV is compressed” … What is it?

Tags: windows-7, boot

Since a couple of days, my computer (Windows 7 only) doesn't want to start : It just say me "GYIAV is compressed".

I Googled it but found absolutely nothing about it ! I tried with the Windows repair CD but I can do nothing with the repair function (no restoration points)

So I'm asking you if someone has already encountered this problem, or at least, if someone can tell me what is this "GYIAV" ?

Comment: Are you sure that was GYIAV? I know only the error message: "BOOTMGR is compressed" . In this case (or anyway) take a look: https://neosmart.net/wiki/bootmgr-is-compressed/

Comment: Is GYIAV even a real thing? In the body, you spell it GYAV and GYIAV?

Comment: Yes it's a real thing, But, my mistake : I edited the body, it's "GYIAV"

Answer (score 0):

Your system is in dire need of a chkdsk.
Your chances are better than most to repair and regain your system with your install CD.

Reboot with your install CD, the menu options aren't in front of me but you maneuver your way into the command prompt option and assuming the install CD and your %systemdrive% is "c"

chkdsk /f /x /v /r ***c:***

based on the size of the disk it can take hours to complete but will thoroughly fix filesystem errors before you uncompress the entire volume unless space is tight and you can't offload files, at least uncompress the entire %systemroot%  ( c:\windows ) directory since the NTFS compression driver depends on lower level drivers successful load.

compact /u /s:c: /i

*tight space*
compact /u /s:c:\windows /i

This used to be a common occurrence with dual booters uninitiated with how Windows boots, assuming this wasn't done by malware you may have compressed the partition and errant windows while the drive was mounted by a different OS.

Was that a possibility? If so you might have a shorter day w/o reinstalling than you're fearing, but if you did get infected, there is a decent offline "virus repair" solution from MS itself Windows Defender Offline with the latest def's and granma proof easy to run for automatically detecting and removing viruses w little interaction.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline

Restore points *might* fix this, but I've personally and professionally found MS Restore points to be more effective in repairing localized profile issues when a users personal preferences stored in the profile need repairing but less effective in repairing unbootable systems like yours.

You can still safely compress the system from itself since files locked in use won't compress while the same OS is awake.

The topic raises entirely jihadic disagreements about compression performance impacts that are your responsibility to investigate their relevance to you.

I've personally used compressed workstations since Windows 2000 with negligible performance impact nor increased boot cycles but the variables are vast and your post will attract excessive opinions on the matter.

Comment: Chkdsk is running, I take you infomed ; anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: No, it doesn't work. And i don't really understand the prupose of the compact command (and windows doesn't reconize it so...)

Comment: @Polo - It should work.  I just tested it.